# Auth0 "tenant must have a name"

Tags: auth0

I'm trying to create a new account and I can login but I get to the page that asks my account name, region, company name and role.

I've input in all fields and accepted the terms and conditions but run into an error that says tenant must have a name. I'm not sure what tenant refers to and how I should fill out the form to proceed.

Comment: I'm having the issue as well. I think there may be a bug in their registration process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem on Auth0's side. I'm experiencing it too. I've opened a bug report on their forum here: https://ask.auth0.com/t/signup-flow-causes-tenant-must-have-a-name/2495.